# How do I add custom data to a ListView widget in Unreal?

Tags: unreal-4, blueprints

I have a UserWidget object with a ListView in it.

How do I add objects add and custom data to them, such as names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First read the tooltip info:

[image]

To add an item with custom properties, you need the following parts:

- List View
- Data entry object
- Presentation widget

The idea behind this setup is most likely to keep data and presentation separated.

#### Data entry object

The data entry object's purpose is only to store data. Create it as a Blueprint class that inherits from Object.

When we add new items to the ListView, we create a new data entry object:

[image]

**Important:** To make FruitName visible, that property needs to have the following settings enabled in the data entry object (BP_Fruit_Data_Entry):

[image]

#### Presentation widget

This is what we tell our ListView that we want to display. We do it here:

[image]

**Important**: In order for our Presentation widget (W_Fruit_Presentation_Widget) to be shown here, it needs to:

1. Inherit from **UserWidget**
2. Implement the **User Object List Entry** interface:
   [image]

#### Presenting the data

When you have added a new data entry object to your list, it will automatically create a new presentation widget of the class that you defined.

When it does that, it will call **On List Item Object Set**. This is where you take the data and put make it presentable:

[image]

Here's an overview on how it works:

[image]

I created an example project a simple setup here: https://github.com/01F0/umg-listview-example

Comment: Thanks for this! I don't know how I would have figured out that I need to implement that interface on my own!

Comment: @BenMora Happy to help! :) I just want to add that a scrollbox + vertical view + custom widget could be enough in most cases.. https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/widget-listview-and-relative-types-of-lists-do-not-behave-as-you-would-expect/141823/3